# Intervening a nodejs process from another process - Is that possible

Tags: node.js

I am currently running a nodejs process which sends a request to an array of several URLs every minute.

It uses the setTimeout to sleep and send the request each minute.

Is that possible to remove any of that items in the array from another nodejs process?

P.S. I simply have an admin interface where I remove these URLs, when a URL is removed I simply want to remove it from the array.

I can do this by checking the database each time before sending the request and if the URL is deleted, remove the item from the array but trying to do that without database checks each time for each URL.

Thanks much.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. In my opinion I would keep it simple and query for the full list of URL's each time.

Comment: The db is huge and don't want to do that. Else, yes, that's the simplest option. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running two totally separate processes, they could send each other signals:

- http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal

(signal.kill sounds scary but it just sends a signal to another process)

You could also use redis as a really simple data sharing mechanism locally.
Of course, you could also just use a file - if you're hitting seven URLs once per minute, a file would be just fine. Check out node-dirty for a nice interface:

- https://github.com/felixge/node-dirty

Comment: That sounds like what I'm looking for. Actually, using a message queue is the best option but I'm trying to accomplish that without a message queue.

Thanks very much.

Comment: node-dirty looks cool too. The code currently runs on mysql but can definitely use this for any other.